# What is the correct syntax to access an object property in PHP?

Tags: php, json

TIA for your help.

I have a script that makes a call to an API. It returns a JSON object and I get an error when I run the script in WAMP, but no problems when I run it on OSX.

This is the line in question:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);

if ($obj->{'Status'} == 'OK'){...}
```

It runs perfect on OSX, but when I run in on WAMP I get the following error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.

I checked and the JSON module is enabled on both installations.

Not sure what else to check for, or if I'm using the wrong syntax.

Thanks

Comment: `$obj->Status` but the error message you're getting indicates that `$obj` is not properly getting initialized on your WAMP server

Comment: Adding the JSON string to your question will make it is easier to answer.

Comment: You don't need any object syntax on **non-object** :)

Comment: Debugging 101 `var_dump($obj);` and let us see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. All of the answers above are correct and different ways to fix my original syntax question.
However, I found out that the difference between my WAMP and OSX installations is that in WAMP, the following was required:
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`
That is why my $obj varible was null in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `->` syntax, but if the keys have characters that are out of the range of valid identifiers in PHP, you could also change your call to `json_decode` to this:

`json_decode($json, true);`

This will return an associative array, and you can access elements with the `[]` syntax like so;

`$obj['Status'];`

Answer (score 1):

Simply, `$object->property` would be the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

If php is unable to decode the json using `json_decode`, `$obj` will have a value of `null` so it will not be an object. This might be the reason why you get this error.

It is best to make sure that the json is parsed correctly. Like so:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (isset($obj) && $obj->status === 'OK') {...}
```

Also, the best way to read the property of an object is using the name of the property directly after the arrow as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Usually,in php you can access attributes of an object by using "$obj->status" or "foreach ($obj as $key => $value)" to get the attribute value.